# Is there a better solution to pop some items from a list using a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

First time poster and recent self-taught beginner at [python](/questions/tagged/python).

I looked up questions on stack overflow, but haven't seen something exactly the same. I want to loop through a whole list, and if an item meets a condition then pop it into a different list. Using a for loop doesn't work as once an item is removed then there are not enough items in the list to complete the initial range. I wrote this code (a pseudo for loop using while) that I think works OK, but would like to know if it is correct or if there is a better/more elegant/more efficient way?

```
while i < len(mylist):
    if mylist[i] > 12:
        mydiscard.append(mylist.pop(i))
        continue
    i+=1
```

Comment: This would belong on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using list comprehensions to generate the 2 lists you want.

```
mydiscard = [x for x in mylist if x > 12]
mylist = [x for x in mylist if x <= 12]
```

Comment: @GreyArea it also makes two passes over the original list instead of one ...